# SQL Server triggers to check credit card balance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I've been trying to find a solution to a very simple problem, but I just cant find out how to do it. I have two tables `Transactions` and `Credit_Card`.

**Transactions**

```
transid (PK), ccid (FK: to credit_card > ccid), amount, timestamp
```

**Credit_Card**

```
ccid (PK), Balance, creditlimit
```

I want to create a trigger so before someone inserts a transaction it checks that the transaction amount + the balance of the credit card does not go over the `creditlimit` and if it is, it rejects the insert.

"**EDIT**" The following code fixed my issue, big thanks to **Dan Guzman** for his contribution!

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_transactions
ON transactions FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS(
SELECT 1
FROM (
    SELECT t.ccid, SUM(t.amount) AS amount
    FROM inserted AS t
    GROUP BY t.ccid) AS t
JOIN Credit_Card AS cc ON
    cc.ccid = t.ccid
WHERE cc.creditlimit <= (t.amount + cc.balance)
)
BEGIN
RAISERROR('Credit limit exceeded', 16, 1);
ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Comment: please edit post with what have you tried so far.

Comment: Please state the issue - do you get an error or does it not function as expected? Do you have a test script to reproduce the issue?

Comment: One obvious issue is that for example the table `transactions` would have many records but you try to load one (random) one into `@ccid`. That doesn't make logical sense (and probably gives you an error - **post it**). You probably want `inserted` instead of `transactions`. Do things one step at a time, verify each step then go to the next step. Also consider that triggers run for ~all~ rows inserted. You might have 10 rows inserted for 10 different credit cards but only one of them goes over balance. Your trigger can only stop **all** 10 records being inserted.

Comment: To expand on what Nick said: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you just need to check the credit limit against newly inserted/updated transactions.  Keep in mind that a SQL Server trigger fires once per statement and a statement may affect multiple rows.  The virtual `inserted` will have images of the affected rows.  You can use this to limit the credit check to only the credit cards affected by the related transactions.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_transactions
ON transactions FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM (
        SELECT inserted.ccid, SUM(inserted.amount) AS amount
        FROM inserted
        GROUP BY inserted.ccid) AS t
    JOIN Credit_Card AS cc ON
        cc.ccid = t.ccid
    WHERE cc.creditlimit <= (t.amount + cc.balance)
    )
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Credit limit exceeded', 16, 1);
    ROLLBACK;
END;
```

**EDIT**
I removed the `t` alias from the inserted table and qualified the columns with `inserted` instead to better indicate the source of the data.  It's generally a good practice to qualify column names with the table name or alias in multi-table queries to avoid ambiguity.

The integers 16 and 1 in the `RAISERROR` statement specify the severity and state of the raised error.  See the [SQL Server Books Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) reference for details.   Severity 11 and greater raise an error, with severities in the 11 through 16 range indicating a user-correctable error.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code made things easier to understand, although I tried  running the trigger it returns with "Msg 1011, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TR_transactions, Line 4
The correlation name 'cc' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause." thanks for your help!

Comment: @Epic117, I corrected the derived table alias.  It should have been `t` rather than `cc`.

Comment: Thank you very much, everything is working as intended, thanks for taking your time helping me out!

Comment: One last thing, could you explain to me what the "from inserted as t" line does and also what are the two numbers inside the raiserror(16,1) thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

you can try this.

ALTER trigger [dbo].[TrigerOnInsertPonches]
On [dbo].[CHECKINOUT]
After Insert 
As
    BEGIN
        DECLARE  @ccid int
        ,@amount money

you have to tell sql that the trigger is ofter insert,
then you can declare the using variable. declare

```
select  @ccid=o.ccid from inserted o;
```

I think is the correct whey to catch the id. 
then you can make the select filtiering from this value.

I hope this can be usefull

Comment: thanks for the reply, I got more lost after following your suggestion, but I am very grateful for your reply, I'll keep trying and googling and update if I get anything new, any other feedback would be great